# FxCop and memory leak hunting

Tags: c#, .net, fxcop

According MSDN, FxCop is an application that analyzes managed code assemblies (code that targets the .NET Framework common language runtime) and reports information about the assemblies, such as possible design, localization, performance, and security improvements.

Is there any predefined rules for FxCop, which can be used for discovering potential memory leak code?

UPDATE : Here is results of my investigation using ANTS Memory Profiler - [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dkcplop6ai0rn6s/Mem_leack.xlsx)

It shows only unmanaged memory increased.. Maybe I'm using it not in a proper way. I will be glad for any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FxCop is not the right tool to discover memory leak. It is something you use to make sure your code is following established guidelines.

There are a few memory Profilers available in the market [.Net Memory Profiler](http://memprofiler.com/), [JetBrains dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/), [ANTS Profiler from RedGate](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/)

Answer (score 2):

FxCop has rules related to undisposed objects. Failing to call Dispose or otherwise (via using blocks) dispose of objects implementing IDisposable could potentially result in leaks. However, I would not consider FxCop a primary tool for identifying memory leaks.

These StackOverflow questions cover the topic of suitable tools created specifically for identifying memory leaks:

[What strategies and tools are useful for finding memory leaks in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134086/what-strategies-and-tools-are-useful-for-finding-memory-leaks-in-net)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259433/how-to-detect-memory-leaks-in-c-sharp-application

One of the tools I've used in the past is AQTime, which does both performance profiling and allocation analysis. The Standard version is free to use: http://smartbear.com/products/free-tools/aqtime-standard

Comment: So, If you were me, what would you use?

Comment: We use Memory Validator primarily. It is a commercial product, but it has a trial period that allows individuals or organizations a chance to try it out to see what it can do and if it is worth the price to them.

Answer (score 0):

The CLR Profiler is free and includes some memory profiling tools.  Here is the one for .NET 4:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16273