# lock is not working properly in c# web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, web-applications

I have created function into that I have created one lock so no other one access that code until first call finish. Under this lock I am running parallel threads and into that thread I am calling function which also have there own lock but some how first lock is not working after sometime and application get crash.

```
static readonly object _syncCoreLock = new object();

internal void ExecuteCatalogTablePopulationThreads()
    {
        lock (_syncCoreLock)
        {
            currentContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
            System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<System.Action> actions = this.CheckCacheAndExecuteActionIfCacheExpired();

            if (actions.Count > 0)
            {
                System.Action[] methodsToExecute = new System.Action[actions.Count];
                actions.CopyTo(methodsToExecute, 0);
                homeCategoryId = DefaultParametersForCatalog.HomeCategoryId.ToString();
                System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.Invoke(new System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = actions.Count }, methodsToExecute);
            }

            this.ExecuteMetaTablesQueryInMultipleThreads<AttributeStringMetaDictionary>();

            if (this.isExecuteProductMetaAttributeQueryThread || this.isExecuteSkuMetaAttributeQueryThread)
            {
                this.SearchDataDictionary = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, SearchKeywordDictionary>();
                System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.Invoke(new System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3 },
                    () => this.ExecuteQualifierTableInThread<ProductQualifier>(),
                    () => this.ExecuteCrossSellingTableInThread<CrossSellingProduct>(),
                    () => this.ExecuteProductSkuMapping());
            }

            if (this.isExecuteCategoryMetaAttributeQueryThread || this.isExecuteProductMetaAttributeQueryThread)
                System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.Invoke(new System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 },
                                                        () => this.ExecuteProductCategoryAndQualifierMapping(),
                                                        () => this.ExecuteCategoryMetaFieldMapping());

            if (this.isExecuteProductMetaAttributeQueryThread || this.isExecuteSkuMetaAttributeQueryThread)
            {
                this.ExecuteProductMetaFieldMapping();
                this.ExecuteSkuMetaFieldMapping();

                this.ExecuteCrossSellingProductMapping();

                this.SearchKeyWordDataDictionary = new System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<SearchKeywordDictionary>(this.SearchDataDictionary.Values);
                Cache.Insert(searchDataDictionaryCacheKey, this.SearchKeyWordDataDictionary);
            }

            if (this.isExecuteDiscountMappingThread)
                ExecuteProductDiscountMapping(); 
 }
}
```

It throw below error sometime :

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
>      at System.Data.Linq.IdentityManager.StandardIdentityManager.IdentityCache`2.Resize()
>      at System.Data.Linq.IdentityManager.StandardIdentityManager.IdentityCache`2.Find(K key, T& value, Boolean add)
>      at System.Data.Linq.IdentityManager.StandardIdentityManager.IdentityCache`2.InsertLookup(Object instance)
>      at System.Data.Linq.IdentityManager.StandardIdentityManager.InsertLookup(MetaType type, Object instance)
>      at System.Data.Linq.CommonDataServices.InsertLookupCachedObject(MetaType type, Object instance)
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReaderBase`1.InsertLookup(Int32 iMetaType, Object instance)
>      at Read_UpSellingProduct(ObjectMaterializer`1 )
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext()

can anybody tell me what is the problem?

Thanks,
Sandy

Comment: Do you still get the OutOfMemory exception if you run it with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1`?

Comment: Yup, after few days it came again.

Comment: So why do you think it's the locking that's the problem? Couldn't your code just be leaking memory?

Comment: may be, but it work 2-3 days and after that it throw the error. Does that mean memory leaking problem?

Comment: That is a common cause of an `OutOfMemoryException`, yes.

Comment: okay, can you suggest me how to check the memory leak.

Comment: Well, that's a whole other question. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134086/what-strategies-and-tools-are-useful-for-finding-memory-leaks-in-net for a start, and make sure you're disposing of objects correctly.

Comment: Yes, it is creating objects continuously. Because of lock is not holding the other calls in wait state.

Comment: can anyone help me on this issue?